# Creating docker image of my system in its current state

Tags: docker, debootstrap

I want to create a docker image of my own system in its current state. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/), i found a method that uses the [debootstrap tool](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye-backports/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html) to create an image:

```
$ sudo debootstrap focal focal > /dev/null
$ sudo tar -C focal -c . | docker import - focal
```

According to debootstrap documentation:

```
debootstrap [OPTION...] SUITE TARGET [MIRROR [SCRIPT]]
debootstrap bootstraps a basic Debian system of SUITE into TARGET from
MIRROR by running SCRIPT. MIRROR can be an http:// or https:// URL, a
file:/// URL, or an ssh:/// URL., a file:///(...)
```

i am no expert in operational systems, so it isnt clear to me if this tool works as i intend. Trying to copy all my system i naively tried:

```
sudo debootstrap / my_system > /dev/null
```

in the hopes that, since files are accepted, "/" would represent my root directory and all would be used by debootstrap. It didnt work. It just generated a folder called my_system with a subfolder called debootstrap and a file called debootstrap.log with the content:

> /usr/sbin/debootstrap: 484: : Permission denied

any tips on how to do this or suggestion of better tools to create docker images of my current installation?

Edit after Virsacer comment about X-Y question:
Adding context: the need to create a docker image from my system came because a given project has fallen into my hands and i need to understand the project quickly. My main idea was to create an environment that would simulate the project operating environment so that i could test new implementations and, in general, make modifications without screwing things up.

Three main things make my job difficult:

1 - It is not just a set of codes. The operating environment itself is part of the project since its made to control and monitor in-house made hardware.

2 - It is not well documented. I have little detail about what services need to be running, what environment vars need to be set, etc. for the whole project to work.

3 -  The only testing environments i have right now are the ones that are already being used, so testing is pretty limited to not affect current operation.

I had two strategies in mind to be able to create my simulating environment: [making an ISO image](https://linuxhint.com/create-iso-current-installation-ubuntu/) of the system and making a docker image of the system.

Making an ISO image seems plausible, but i wanted to
1 - Seize the oportunity to learn something new;
2 - Have the redundancy of creating the environment in two different working ways.
3 - Have the container as a more portable way of replicating the environment when needed.

So i thought about creating the image, continuously getting rid of anything that doesnt seem needed for the project, testing and creating
a new, lighter image if testing results successful.

Comment: x-y question? Why do you need an docker image of your system? Docker is about minimalization: Use an existing base-image or an empty image and just add the libraries/binaries that you really need.

Comment: @Virsacer indeed i thought about adding the source of the need as context, but it seemed too qualitative and i thought questions too open to subjectivity would not be well seen here.
I tried adding the source of problem here as a comment but its too big, so i will edit the question to add it. Thanks!

Comment: debootsrap installs a minimal copy of debian in the directory specified. You don't need this, you already have a system installed in `/`. What you need is a tar of `/`, which you can feed to docker import. You can't just use `cd / ; tar -c . ` as the tar will include the filestore backing the docker, so will include the tar and you will run out of disk. You need  a more selective tar command to not contain everything on your system, or a different place to store the tarball, e.g. a usb drive.

Comment: @icarus i did it with `tar --ignore-failed-read -zcvf - / -S | ssh marco@<other_computer> "cat > system.tgz"` to send the content via ssh to other computer using it as storage. The tar process worked but when i tried `docker import - system.tgz` i waited 24 hours and my terminal just didnt come back. So im gessing its too big to be made a docker image?

Comment: Using ssh is a great solution to finding somewhere else to store things not under /. I doubt that the issue is that the resulting tar is "too big", I think you have the command wrong and it is spending 24 hours waiting for you to type the tarball in from your keyboard! `docker import system.tgz myimage`.

Comment: Thanks, @icarus! I tried `docker import system.tgz myimage` yesterday but again it took too long and i killed the process. Im trying again today with a little more time in my hands to see if i get any output. Will update at the end of the day.

Comment: @icarus waiting 9 hours for the `docker import system.tgz myimage` command to exit and nothing happened. Killed the terminal again.
Maybe some sparse file got in the way? But i think the -S in the tar command should prevent that...